# javascript change event or keybord input event so button can be enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

site: https://www.verizonwireless.com/5g/home/

input: "132 W Gale street, Philadelphia, PA"

If I enter this address manually with keyboard "Check Availability" button is enabled. I want to perform a fire event or change event to enable the button after setting the text.

None of solution seems to be enabling the button.

I have tried evaluate and querySelector. also jQuery

```
var xp="//*[@id='streetAddress]"
var e = document.evaluate(xp, document, null, 9, null ).singleNodeValue;
e.value="132 W Gale street, Philadelphia, PA";
e.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

also I have tried following.
var e = document.querySelector("#streetAddress");
e.value="132 W Gale street, Philadelphia, PA";
e.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an onchange handler to street address input then use `$(element).attr("disabled",false);` to remove the disabled attribute of check availability button.

Run the code below.

Edit: `$("#streetAddress").change();` will call the onchange event handler. So everytime you programmatically update the field, call .change on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // handle onchange event
  $("#streetAddress").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "132 W Gale street, Philadelphia, PA") {
      alert("Gotcha, enabling button.");
      $(".checkAvlButton").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $(".checkAvlButton").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });

  $(".checkAvlButton").click(function() {
    alert("Availability button clicked!");
  });

  // on page load, fill street address then call .change() to initiate handler
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#streetAddress").val("132 W Gale street, Philadelphia, PA");
    $("#streetAddress").change();
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input id="streetAddress" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="checkAvlButton" disabled>Check Availability</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: I tried removing the attribute disabled and class "is-disabled" but I am getting following error when I click. "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved it.
here is my solution.

```
var e = document.querySelector("streetAddress");
var evnt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
evnt.initKeyboardEvent('keyup', true, true, document.defaultView, 'Enter', 0, '', false, '');
e.dispatchEvent(evnt);
```